# Como juntar as celulas de uma tabela

Tags: css, tabela-html

Boa noite! Estou fazendo um WHILE dos dados vindo do banco de dados para uma tabela usando css mas não consegui fazer que as células da tabela ficassem juntas e com a mesma borda. Um exemplo da tabela que fiz:

```css
table{
   width: 100%;
}

table td{
   padding: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         OK
      </td>
      <td>
         OK
      </td>
      <td>
         OK
      </td>
      <td>
         OK
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Como remover esses espaços entre as celulas usando apenas css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi o problema, de forma simples tratam-se dos atributos

border-spacing: 0;
border-collapse: collapse;

```css
table
{
            width: 100%;
            border-spacing: 0;
            border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td
{
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid black;
            
}
```

```html
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    OK
                </td>
                <td>
                    OK
                </td>
                <td>
                    OK
                </td>
                <td>
                    OK
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Mais detalhes podem em   https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Pergunta semelhante: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu queria. tão simples e eu não conseguia.